# gets.chomp three times in a row to exit

Tags: ruby

The task is taken from "Learn to Program" by Chrise Pine. The program is called 'Deaf Grandma'. Here's the task: "whatever you type, grandma (the program) should respond with this:

```
    `HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!`
```

unless you shout it (type in all capitals). In this case she responds with:

```
    `NO, NOT SINCE 1938!`
```

Have Grandma shout a different year each time, maybe any year at random between 1930 and 1950. You have to shout BYE three times in a row. Make sure to test your program: if you shout
BYE three times but not in a row, you should still be talking to
Grandma." 
Now, everything looks fine to me, except I didn't get where to put `gets.chomp` 3 times to exit a program. Eventually, I came up with this:

```
    speak = gets.chomp 
     while speak != 'BYE' 
       puts 'HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
     if speak == speak.upcase
       puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + (1930 + rand(20)).to_s + '!'
     else repeat = gets.chomp
     end
    end
```

But in this case if I type `BYE` grandma still asks me:

```
    `HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!`
```

My question is: how can I properly make the program exit after I type `BYE` three times in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this, I've made some changes though. But should give you the expected output.

```
bye_count = 0
while true
  speak = gets.chomp
  if speak == 'BYE'
    bye_count +=1
    bye_count == 3 ? break : next
  end
  bye_count = 0 # Resets count
  if speak == speak.upcase
    puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + (1930 + rand(20)).to_s + '!'
  else
    puts 'HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked just fine, thank you! I didn't learn anything about 'count' yet.

Comment: `count` was just a variable i used. I've renamed it to `bye_count` to make it more cleared

Comment: Got it. But it means that whether you write BYE three times in a row or  something else in between, it still breaks after the 3d time. How can I make it so that even if you type BYE twice, and the third time something different, you will still have to say BYE from the beginning 3 times in a row?

Comment: I had updated the answer to meet that criteria also. Please see line 8, where i reset the `bye_count`

Answer (score 1):

You've not added anywhere in your code that using 'bye' 3 times will exit the program.

`while bye < 3`

Try looking at your code again and implementing the changes to exit after 3 byes.

Comment: I tried 
    'while 'BYE' < 3' 
but it said 
    'comparison of String with 3 failed'. Should I make a variable for 'BYE'?

Comment: Alfie above has given you the answer you needed... As you are learning I didn't want to just give you the answer outright but keep going, you're doing great!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
responses = ["", "", ""]

loop do
  speak = gets.chomp
  responses.shift
  responses << speak
  break if responses.all? { |r| r == "BYE" }
  if speak == speak.upcase
    puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + (1930 + rand(20)).to_s + '!'
  else
    puts 'HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
  end
end
```

Alternatively,

```
break if responses.uniq == ["BYE"]
```

Comment: I don't know what exactly I'm missing here, but it gives me an error "undefined local variable or method 'speak'" after I have finished the code with 
  'if speak == speak.upcase
  puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + (1930 + rand(21)).to_s + '!' 
  else puts 'HUH? SPEAK UP, SONNY!' 
end'

Comment: My apologies for not testing my code. I initially wrote `do loop`, rather than `loop do`. I also added the `if speak == speak.upcase` code. It seems to work fine now.

Comment: Yep, that works just fine. But is it possible to modify this code (using the same loop do) so that when you say BYE she doesn't respond with anything?

Comment: You could insert the line `next if speak=="BYE"` after `break if...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "what can i do for your son?"
a=0
while a != 3
n= gets.chomp
  if n.include? 'BYE'
    puts "NO NOT SINCE  #{rand(1897..1930)}".chomp
    a = (a + 1)
  end
  if n != n.upcase
    puts 'HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!'.chomp
    a=0 
  end
  if n == n.upcase and n != 'BYE'
    puts "NO NOT SINCE  #{rand(1897..1930)}".chomp
    a=0
  end
end
```